# How to save multiple contact?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone app which require to save multiple contact. I have store the contact in list. I want to save the contact one by one.

Here is my code

```
  var data = from q in document.Descendants("Contact")
                   select new ContactList
                   {
                       DisplayName = q.Element("Name").Value,
                       Email = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.Element("Email").Value) ? q.Element("Email").Value : " ",
                       Address = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.Element("Address").Value) ? q.Element("Address").Value : " ",
                       //PhoneNumber = m.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault()
                       PhoneNumber = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.Element("PhoneNumber").Value) ? q.Element("PhoneNumber").Value : " "
                   };

        ContactList con = null;            
        SaveContactList = new List<ContactList>();

        foreach (var c in data)
        {
            con = new ContactList();
            con.DisplayName = c.DisplayName;
            con.Address = c.Address;
            con.Email = c.Email;
            con.PhoneNumber = c.PhoneNumber;                
            SaveContactList.Add(con);         
        }
```

Here I have store all contact in **SaveContactList**. Now I want to save all these contact. How can I save these contact ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to save them to Windows Phone Phonebook - there is no way to save all contacts at a time.

You can only save them 1 by 1, you may use foreach

Sample to save contact:

```
var phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask
        {
            DisplayName = ContactName.Text,
            PhoneNumber = phonetext.Text
        };
        phoneCallTask.Show();
```